# How to find the oldest article on Slashdot?

Tags: search, slashdot

I just clicked on a link that was an article posted on slashdot in 2003. It discusses Python vs Perl and it was quite interesting to read the comments from that time. How can I find the oldest articles posted on Slashdot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Slashdot articles have the article ID in the URL, which is incremented with each article, so just taking any article, and putting "1" where is the article id in the URL will reveal the oldest one.

This one might be it: http://slashdot.org/story/1/
There is some discussion about the very topic there, and there seems to be some error.

Then it seems there is a tag for the first post on Slashdot:

http://slashdot.org/tag/firstpost

Which links to an article from December 31 1997:

http://slashdot.org/story/98/01/01/012000/become-007-on-the-internet